# Compare all feature branches with master

Tags: sonarqube

In SonarQube, I have a project for my `master` branch and a project for each feature branch: `feature/someFeature`.

I would like that when any of the projects corresponding to my feature branches is analysed, it should be compared with my `master` branch project. And in case the projects for my feature branches have worse code coverage or overall grade, I would like the Quality Gates to fail.

Any idea how to do that using SonarQube?

Answer (score 1):

Not easy but you can try a '@BatchSide' (implements PostJob) plugin, with :

1- load last master analyse with web api rest (new GetRequest("api/....)

2- consider curent analys results with the PostJobContext Object

3- do your own business and then throw MessageException.of("too much errors comparer to master branch");